# Need to identify difference in the output of fqlquery and json decoding

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have a database table that has facebook page url, page id and status. I need to update the status field with Yes or No depending on whether the facebook page is verified or not. I have taken the fql approach (i know its no more now) still. It works because I have an old facebook app. Here is the query outputs json object returning true or false

```
FQL Query
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT is_verified FROM page WHERE page_id="115332808485663"
```

[Link to view query in browser](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20is_verified%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=%22115332808485663%22)

Here I have taken an example of NokiaIndia facebook page. It is a verified page and the above query returns true in brower but when i do it in php, it says its not verified. I think I have some thing wrong in the below code that needs to be identified. Please help.

```
  $url=$row["url"];
  $pageid=$row["page_id"];

    $fqlAPIParams = array(
              'method' => 'fql.query',

                'query' =>' 
                  SELECT  is_verified
                  FROM    page
                  WHERE   page_id = '.$pageid.'  
                      LIMIT 99999' ,
                      'access_token'=>$token
               );

    $result = $facebook->api($fqlAPIParams);

 if( $result->is_verified ){
    $verified="Yes";
  } else {
    $verified="No";
  }

echo $pageid;
echo "<br>";
echo $verified;
```

Here is the output of the code. Since the page in example is verified, it should show Yes ! Please help....

```
115332808485663
No
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should be checking the "is_verified" field, but you are checking "verified".

It should be:

```
if( $result->is_verified ){
    $verified="Yes";
} else {
    $verified="No";
}
```

Comment: haha! that was a typo! Thanks... but it is still giving "No". Any idea why

Comment: Another thing: you are looping through all $post in $result, but you are asking for $result->is_verified. Maybe try $post->is_verified?

Comment: I have deliberately kept the post for something else that I intend to do in the future. As per your advice, I have removed that too still "No" question updated with $post. How to echo the entire json object? may be that can help diagnose the issue.

Comment: print_r($result); produces a result Array ( [0] => Array ( [is_verified] => 1 ) ) now how can i get the value 1 in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Being having very little knowledge of arrays, json and programming, Tired a lot of combinations and finally got it to work. The problem was here

```
 if( $result[0]['is_verified'] ){
```